# Yii2 - ActiveForm - $form->field returns ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: yii2

I have a Yii2 advance template site, which runs fine on my local server (Vagrant Ubuntu 14.04 install with php7.0)

The Server (where the error is) is an Ubuntu 16.04 with Php7.0 install 
(I specifically create a vagrant box with same installed php7.0 on my local dev to have about similar install as the server)

My pages are working fine on my local dev, but on the server, I had issues opening some of the pages - where it only returns ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and a blank page.

I traced the source of the error down to the following:

As soon as I call something like :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'Consent') ?>
```

Then the page on the server just returns a blank page with the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error, the rest like

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

Works fine, as soon as I have a $form->field, then it bombs out?

I see no indication in a log or the site error logs to indicate why?

Question is, is there an alternative then to using $form->field, or why would it work fine on one server and not another?

IF any more details required please let me know how and what to provide

Thank you in advance

Comment: If I search for ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE I get the impression that it might have something to do either with Chrome or with some connection problems. Possibly it is not caused by Yii? Just an idea...

Comment: Thanks robsch, thing is I get it in IE, Opera and different devices on different connections, 3G, DSL etc. It seems that this server instance fails to create my model object. When I try to check or say var dump the $model in the view there is none, on my local server however there is